# Laptop shuts down immediately after Windows 8 Logo?

Tags: windows, laptop, boot

I'm using a relatively new Alienware m17x R4 running Windows 8 (installed last week) and yesterday when booting up the laptop will shut down during/after the Windows 8 spinning circle screen.

I am able to run a diagnostics test and everything comes back as being okay, hard drive, processor, RAM, graphics cards, temperatures, battery, power and fans all are running fine. However this problem seems to persist and I can't get past the Windows logo.

Most answers to questions like this point to a hardware issue, but is that the case if the diagnostics says everything is fine? Is this a software issue?

Tried booting it in various ways, with power, no power, not battery with power, all the same result. Also, when I press F8 to boot into safe mode I just get a really loud continuous beep. What's going on there?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, I think I may have solved it myself. I was about to give up and format it, noticed 'repair disk' in the Windows 7 install CD options, tried it, got back into Windows 8 and discovered it was caused by updating my graphics driver to one that's 'compatible with Windows 8'.. think I'll stick with the non-compatible one thank you. Crisis averted!